# Why am I not able to answer a protected question, even though I have 101 reputation points?

Tags: support

I am a new user on this site, but I already participate in other sites of the network. So by creating profile here, I gained 100 reputation points.

But by visiting [**this question**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5778/39804), I came across the message below, even though I have a reputation above 10:

[image]

I do not intend to answer this question, but I found it curious to have this restriction, even though I have all the limits of users with more than 100 reputation released.

This is correct or possible bug?

Comment: Is that in Portuguese because your browser translated it, or am I missing something here? :P

Comment: miss read, my bad :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to *earn* 10 reputation points to be able to answer protected questions. The warning itself mentions that the association bonus does not count.